# cannot autowire resttemplate in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired, resttemplate

here is my configuration class.

```
@Component
public class Teamplate {
    @Bean(name="restProxy")
    public RestTemplate restProxy() {

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
            String proxyHost = "10.123.10";
            String proxyPort = "8080";
            String proxyUser = "test";
            String proxyPassword = "test";
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    if (getRequestorType().equals(RequestorType.PROXY)) {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(proxyUser, proxyPassword.toCharArray());
                    }
                    return super.getPasswordAuthentication();
                }
            });
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

here is my main class

```
@Component
public class Call {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restProxy")
    private RestTemplate restProxy;

    public void send() {
        // some code
        restProxy.exchange(requestEntity, responseType)
        //
    }
}
```

this is my import

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.Proxy.Type;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

this is my pom for resttemplate

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

when i run the application, it says 
Field restProxy in com.x.x.Call required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.

I cannot autowire my resttemplate, I also tried make it @primary, and tag with @Qualifier(value="restProxy ")

Comment: You need to use `@Configuration` not `@Component`

Comment: @123 it doesnt work

Comment: quick question, where are you using `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient` from what I see you are using `Spring's` `RestTemplate` to do API call

Comment: @Avi i am using it when i add timeout, currently it is not used. unnecessary dependency

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue in my local, can you show the `Main class` if you have ignored in `Componentscan`, this problem might come

Comment: @Avi the main class is ok, the service is running well, I was using a project dependency which have resttemplate configuration in it, I removed it and created configuration class, I create a component and try to autowire it myself, now this configuration doesnt work,

Comment: after you mentioned componentscan, I double checked the my configuration class, it is under the @SpringBootApplication class thats whyy my beans are not scaned, ty for answer.